# Fluid Simulation has Blue Dots around the Edges of Baked Mesh

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've searched for an answer and can't find out why my blender is acting up like this and i've messed up everything i can think of: Upres Factor, Resolution Divsions and Substeps Sampling and to no avail but i'm sure the solution is in my face. My image below shows the issue i'm having, it shows in every viewport mode.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already baked the mesh component of your fluid, un-check (disable) the *Liquid* simulation "balls" in the Physics Properties of your Domain object:

[image: DomainBalls]

Comment: Or alternatively, go into the particle settings tab, open liquid, and make the scale slightly lower,  in case you still want to see the particles in wireframe mode.